# How to create your own Route with callback for Auth and Roles for a package

Tags: php, laravel

So, I am working on a package in Laravel, I would like to know if how could we create our own Route with wildcard url?

What if the page request is `/users/1/edit` and we know that this is a rest request.

And I want to implement my own Authentications inside the routes itself, such as:

```
Route::get('/users/{id}/edit', function() {
  // Filtering here..
  // Access Prevention here...
});
```

The only thing I did was to use a null variables to point those routes(with rest request)

Example we have an array to store the custom route lists with auth and so on.

```
return [
  'show_dashboard' => [
     'process' => 'get',
     'uses' => 'MyController@showDashboard',
     'is_auth' => true,
     'roles' => ['admin','superuser','supervisor'],
  ],
];

$routes = Config::get('package::routes');
Route::{$process}($url, function($p1=null,$p2=null,$p3=null,$p4=null,$p5=null) use ($routes) {
  // Filtering here..
  // Access Prevention here...

  App::make($controller)->{$action}($p1,$p2,$p3,$p4,$p5);
});
```

Is there a better way to do this? Because what if the url contains more than 5 wildcards, that's the problem I encountered.

Is there a way in laravel to call the `Router` class and register your own route but also adding your own callback.

Comment: Defining Routes on a package is a bad practice and it breaks the framework Logic. Creating a Middleware where anyone could implement and use would be a better solution in case of Role validations. Routes on packages break out most of SOLID principles.

Comment: So how could I achieve to inject the requested url? Should I provide them a class to be instantiated for every functions/methods of their own controller?

Comment: The end user will have to add the routes you define in their own routes file. The route will then use your controller. Like @Burimi said, do not try to force your own route. You will force the user to use your route which, imo, is not real fair game

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#package-routing

Comment: The only thing I did is to provide a way for the user to automatically secure the route access, github.com/daison12006013/admin-laravel, they could still use the main Route configuration file, however they need to prevent the access by their own style.